# XSL encoding special characters XML wellformed

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding

I need to execute the following mapping.
We receive a (simple) wellformed XML file.
In that xml file there can be special characters - that are encoded. For example &

The output of the mapping needs to look like this:

```
<ns0:SupplierTransaction xmlns:ns0="http://MH.Schemas/SQL/MDM/Supplier">
  <ns0:CIC.ImportSupplier_Spain>
    <ns0:data>&lt;Suppliers xmlns=""&gt;&lt;Supplier&gt;&lt;IDCONO&gt;All Freez &amp;lt; &amp;amp; &amp;gt; (Verp)IZ Oude Bunders&lt;/IDCONO&gt;&lt;/Supplier&gt;&lt;/Suppliers&gt;</ns0:data>
   </ns0:CIC.ImportSupplier_Spain>
 </ns0:SupplierTransaction>
```

So as you can see, I need to encode the xml I receive and wrap it around some nodes.
The issue is that for the special characters (&, <, >), those need to be encoded twice. Because if you parse the ns0:data field back to XML, then it will also parse the "&amp;" back to "&" resulting in invalid XML. It should parse it to &amp; ==> so that is why it should be encoded twice.

My question is, how can I accomplish this in xsl?
So I need to detect the special symbols:

```
"&" and encode it twice: &amp;amp;
"<" and encode it twice: &amp;lt;
">" and encode it twice: &amp;gt;
```

FYI, I am transmitting this message to a SQL procedure. The input parameter of the SQL procedure is called "data" and has the datatype "XML". So SQL parsed everything that is inside the data element to XML and it throws an error at the special characters, if I don't double encode them.
For example:

```
<ns0:data>&lt;Node&gt;This is some text &amp; chars&lt;/Node&gt;</ns0:data>
```

So this is parsed as following:

```
<Node>This is some tekst & chars</Node> ==> Invalid XML
```

It should be the following:

```
<ns0:data>&lt;Node&gt;This is some text &amp;amp; chars&lt;/Node&gt;</ns0:data>
```

Which is parsed as following:

```
<Node>This is some tekst &amp; chars</Node> ==> Valid XML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a job for XSLT, as it sees the original input as a tree of nodes, not as a string of text.  You'd need to manually re-serialize the input document using (hideously complicated) templates.

If you have the original XML as a string then you would be better not to try and parse it and process it as XML, but rather to use an XML writing API in whatever language you're working in to write out an XML document that includes the original string of XML data as the character content of your `ns0:data` element, and let the XML serializer handle all the necessary escaping.  A Java example might be

```java
XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamWriter writer = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
writer.writeStartDocument();
String uri = "http://MH.Schemas/SQL/MDM/Supplier";
writer.writeStartElement("ns0", "SupplierTransaction", uri);
writer.writeStartElement("ns0", "CIC.ImportSupplier_Spain", uri);
writer.writeStartElement("ns0", "data", uri);
writer.writeCharacters(originalXMLString);
writer.writeEndDocument();
writer.close();
outputStream.close();
```

but the equivalent behaviour should be simple to implement in any language.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback. But if I want to convert the part that is in the "ns0:data" node back to XML, will the xml still be valid? For example, let's say I've got the follow string: &lt;Node&gt;This is &amp; text&lt;/&gt; ==> Won't this result into <Node>This is & tekst </Node> which is now invalid XML because the & is not escaped?

Comment: I will add a CDATA section around the nodes, so that the special characters are left alone :) Stupid I didn't think of this earlier :) Thx anyway for the help

Comment: @Rise_against if the original string was `<Node>text &amp; more</Node>` then when you include it as character data as in my example it will be serialized as `&lt;Node&gt;text &amp;amp; more&lt;/Node&gt;` as you require.